# Ajax class in Javascript not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create my own version of the ajax method in Jquery to see how it works:

```
function ajax(url, method) {
    var self = this;
    this.xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    this.xhr.onreadystate = function() {
        self.xhrHandler();
    }
    this.xhr.open(method, url, true);
    this.xhr.send();
}

ajax.prototype.xhrHandler = function() {
    if (this.xhr.readyState == 4) {
        console.log(this.xhr.responseText);
    }
    console.log("test");
}
```

It never goes into the xhrHandler function, though, since it never prints out "test". What is going on?

Edit: Here is a usage example: `var ex = new ajax("www.fake.com/api/item/1/", "GET");`

Comment: Can you give a usage example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The handler is called `onreadystatechange`, not just `onreadystate`.

And (that's a detail), you should also test the `status`.